# программа пропускает if и сразу переходит к else

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

В консоль должно по нажатию кнопки start выводиться что one on или one off и two on или two off взависимости от проставленных флажков в окне tkinter но вместо этого всегда выводиться one off и two off как бы небыли бы выставлены флажки, как я понял программа всегда выводит else: но почему она всегда выводит только else я не понял, работаю на python 3.8 в Idle

вот код:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import datetime as dt


root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400") 
root["bg"] = "grey"



def show():
    s = f'{var1.get()}, ' \
        f'{var2.get()}'  

def buildsettings():
    if var1 == "True":
        print ("two on")

    else:
        print ("one off")


    if var2 == "True":
        print ("two on")

    else: 
        print ("two off")


frame = Frame()
frame.pack(side=LEFT)

var1 = BooleanVar()
var1.set(0)
c1 = Checkbutton(frame, text="one",
                 variable=var1,
                 onvalue=1, offvalue=0,
                 command=show)
c1.pack(anchor=W, padx=10)

var2 = IntVar()
var2.set(-1)
c2 = Checkbutton(frame, text="two",
                 variable=var2,
                 onvalue=1, offvalue=0,
                 command=show)
c2.pack(anchor=W, padx=10)
b = tk.Button(root, text='start', command=buildsettings)
b.place(x=0, y=375)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

True - это переменная bool типа, а не строка. При этом сравнение с True можно опустить `if var1.get()`

Значение переменных tkinter надо брать через `get`

```
def buildsettings():
    if var1.get() == True:
        print ("two on")

    else:
        print ("one off")


    if var2.get() == True:
        print ("two on")

    else: 
        print ("two off")
```